# Interfacing two ICs with different thresholds

Tags: interface, logic-level

I'm trying to using an ADuM1251 (http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADUM1250_1251.pdf) with an ATxmega32A4U (http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-8387-8-and16-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-XMEGA-A4U_Datasheet.pdf).

ADuM1251 (on side 1) has a voltage for low-level output of max 900 mV
ATxmega32A4U recognize as low-level a voltage of max 800 mV (@ 3.3V).

Of course they can't communicate each other!

I would be simple if the data line was unidirectional, but unfortunately I'm talking about the SDA signal that is bidirectional. Hence I cannot use a buffer.

I would use this solution, what do you think about?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAn2AQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Does the side where I put the ICs matter?

Comment: only under *very* bad situation would a low-level threshold difference this small be an issue. I'm not sure you're actually solving your problem. So, you might first want to describe what goes wrong! http://xyproblem.info

Comment: Simply they don't communicate becase the xmega doesn't accept such an high voltage for low level. Some combinations of ADuM and xmega work, others don't. I *must* handle the worst case.

Comment: no. you're comparing the wrong things, as far as I can tell. Can you actually refer by table/page number and entry to why you think this is a problem? Jeroens answer says exactly the same as I do: I don't think you're solving the right issue.

Comment: I don't think that they are not compatible. Also the max. low-level voltage difference shouldn't be an issue. Perhaps your problem comes from an unfortunate filtering issue: Note that the capacitance formed by transmission line and the pull-up resistors form a low-pass filter. With enough capacitance/pull-up resistor combination, signals may be chopped off easily. Are you using long traces for SDA and GND lines between the chips?
 This makes a high capacitance. And also, I²C speed plays an important role here. Maybe you should decrease the speed.

Comment: I see. Well, the I2C lines have a lenght of less than 25 mm. The frequency is 100 kHz. With the oscilloscope I saw sharp edges but a "floor" of 850 mV above ground. Changing with another ADuM1251 the edges were pretty the same but the floor went down below 700 mV. This is why I suspected about levels.

Comment: @Mark - IMHO this question likely cannot be "rescued" now, as the initial question is so different from the *real* problem where *many* more details are needed (due to the *XY problem* as *Marcus* explained). However there are 2 points in your last comment which are vital and, if I was in your situation, I would focus on them: (a) the ' "floor" of 850 mV above ground ' on I2C signals; several investigative paths could be followed there; (b) with 'another ADuM1251 [...] the floor went down below 700 mV'; the lack of consistency between those two "identical" devices is concerning. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

The ADuM1251 has an output low level of *600* - 900 mV when sinking 3 mA.
The ATxmega32A4U has an input low level of *0.5* - 0.3×VCC (990mV).

The ATxmega32A4U has an output low level of 0 - 400 mV at 3 mA. (page 113)
The ADuM1251 has an input low level of 500 - 700 mV when sinking 3 mA.

Both seem compatible to me. Except maybe the *italic* numbers, but you have very bad luck if that takes you down.

*Note: I should add that the sides on the ADuM1251 are not identical.*

Comment: Table 36-103: 0,3xVCC only between 2.0V and 2.7V. At 3.3V the input is max 800 mV. I have a couple of board in front of me. They are NOT compatible. In both ADuM1251 has an output voltage of 850 mV and the xmega doesn't recognize the low level. Other units has 700 mV and work fine. I cannot rely on luck :)

Comment: @Mark table 36-103 does not apply to the i2c interface. Look at Table 36-64.

Comment: not even bad luck: if you *don't* draw 3mA (which is easy – just don't design your board with low-valued pullups, i.e. use anything larger than 1.1kΩ instead), you're on the safe side.

Comment: @Jeroen3 you're right. Because there weren't any notes about on table 36-103 I didn't see the other...

Comment: @MarcusMüller yes, I have 6k8 pull-up resistors

Comment: So, then the voltage thresholds aren't your problem. You're somehow introducing a very solid offset into your system - but since you're already using an isolator IC I assume you're aware of that – maybe your measurement system is referenced to the wrong Ground?